# Vue: How to display different images based on RadioButton choice

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

I am facing a problem where I want to display a different image if a radiobutton is selected with Vuejs. It currently only shows the image for the false state since I do not seem to be able to retrieve the state of the button in the way I tried. Here is an example with two buttons:

```
<template>
  <div id="choose-route">
    <label>
      <input type="radio" name="Radio" id="choice1"
        v-on:change="someMethodOne"
      />
      <img
        :src="checked ? 'icon_checked.png' : 'icon.png'"
      />
    </label>
    <label>
      <input type="radio" name="Radio" id="choice2"
        v-on:change="someMethodTwo"
      />
      <img
        :src="checked ? 'different_icon_checked.png' : 'different_icon.png'"
      />
    </label>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  methods: {
    someMethodOne () {
      // does something
    },
    someMethodTwo () {
      // does another thing
    }
  }
}
</script>

<style>
</style>
```

How do I go about changing the image based on the checked state of the radiobutton? I already did it using CSS, but that lead to another problem due to the fact that I use recursive components which is why I am here now.

Comment: you forgot to define `checked`, if you want multiple then you need a model which contains multiple items i.e and object

Comment: Thank you for your comment @LawrenceCherone, can you please elaborate on what I have to do to fix this?

Comment: set `data:() => ({checked:{choice1:false, choice2:false}})` https://vuejs.org/v2/api/#data then do `:src="checked.choice1 ? ` and `:src="checked.choice2 ? `, rtm this stuff is basics

Comment: and use the model `v-model="checked.choice1"` for the radios not events

Comment: Thanks again @LawrenceCherone, this will help me fix it I guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `v-model`. You can also use `watch` to do something when `checked` value change.

There is this exact example on Vue.js' website.

https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/forms.html#Radio

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    checked: null
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>

  <div id="app">
      <input type="radio" id="one" value='One' v-model="checked">
      <label for="one">Option one</label>
      
      <br>
      
      <input type="radio" id="two" value="Two" v-model="checked">
      <label for="two">Option two</label>
      
      <br>
      
      <span>Checked: {{ checked }}</span>
      
      <br>
      
      <span v-if="checked === 'One'">One is checked!</span>
      <span v-else-if="checked === 'Two'">Two is checked!</span>
  </div>
```